# @Service is not working in Implementation Class

Tags: java, spring, service, autowired

**Interface:**

```
public interface registration service
```

**Implementation Class:**

```
@Service
public class RegistrationServiceImpl implements RegistrationService{

    @Autowired
    RegistrationService registrationService;}
```

**Inside Controller Class:**

```
@Autowired
private RegistrationService registrationService;
```

Hi guys, would like to get a better understanding regarding to service and autowired annotation. Currently, I am placing the Service annotation in the Implementation class, but when I try to use the Autowired annotation in my controller class, I am still getting this error

```
'sample.RegistrationService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}\"}}"
```

May I know why and what would be the solution for it?

Directory of Service:

```
Sample.service.Registration
```

Directory of Controller:

```
Sample.controller.registrationController
```

Comment: May be your `RegistrationServiceImpl` is not scanned by spring, can you also share the package structure of `service`, `controller` and main class if you're using boot?

Comment: As I am using JBOSS, I do not have the main class, I have provided the directory for service and  controller

Comment: Make sure your `@ComopnentScan` is covering both packages, or if you are using Spring Boot make sure the `@SpringBootApplication` class is in the `Sample` package. Also those aren't directories but packages.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT for the correct way of implementation:

> create a @Configuration class and define the @Bean for this service

```
@Configuration
 public class AppConfig{
  @Bean(name = "RegistrationService")
  RegistrationService getRegistrationService(){
    return new RegistrationServiceImpl();
  }
}
```

> If you have more than one implementation for the same interface you can create another bean for the same implementation and use @Qualifier("") below @Autowired for defining what you use

Comment: Which would totally defeat the purpose of the interface.

Comment: Yes @M.Deinum you are correct. I apologize for that wrong answer

Comment: You don't need an `@Configuration` either if component scanning is setup correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Can you please upvote it now @M.Deinum

Comment: I'm not upvoting anything as this doesn't solve the issue at hand.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the  @Autowired service interface bean from serviceImpl class and annotate serviceImpl class as @Service and in controller class autowire the bean of serviceImpl class as below

@Autowired
RegistrationServiceImpl impl;

Comment: but this will defeat the purpose of having the interface layer right ? Since we are bypassing the interface and directly go for the implementation layer

Comment: Which defeats the purpose of interfaces and programming to interfaces. Next to that it can lead to issues with interface proxying instead of class proxying.